# PHP assign where in the link

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdf, pdo

I have coded a php script that will generate a pdf file from some results. My select statement needs to be filtered with a where condition. Basically, I want to test my php script to see if it works well or not. How can I assign the where condition in the link itself? 
this is my php code :

```
 $query = "
        SELECT
            user_id
        FROM TahdirUsers
        WHERE
            username = ':username'
    ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try
{
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
die(json_encode($response));
}

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row)
{
if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password'])
{
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid password!";
    $pdf = new PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION,PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,true, 'UTF-8', true); 

            $pdf->SetFont('aefurat', '', 12, '', true);


            // The first Parameter is localhost again unless you are retrieving data from a different server. 
            // The second parameter is your MySQL User ID. 
            // The third parameter is your password for MySQL. In many cases these would be the same as your OS ID and Password. 
            // The fourth parameter is the Database you'd like to run the report on. 

            $pdf->connect('xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx'); 

            // This is the title of the Report generated. 
            $attr=array('titleFontSize'=>24,'titleText'=>'THIS IS MY PDF FILE'); 
            // This is your query. It should be a 'SELECT' query. 

            // Reports are run over 'SELECT' querires generally. 
            $pdf->mysql_report($query,false,$attr); 
            $pdf->Output('htmlout.pdf', 'I');

    die(json_encode($response));
}
}
  else
{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "this username in not in our database!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
```

To clarify my question. If my website link is www.testtesttest.com, how do I implement the where condition from the select statement in the URL

Comment: You replace your reference to $_POST["username"] with $_GET["username"] and you change your url to www.testtesttest.com/path/to/php/file?username=someusername

Comment: alternatively you can use a client http utility like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) that allows you to specify a post body and use that to perform a post against the relevant url

Comment: I replaced $_POST['username'] to $_GET['username'],,, It still not working

Comment: it always gives me that username is not in the database.

Comment: From what I understand your question: I guess you can safe your username in session and you can fetch username session key to your where statement from any where in your page as long the user is not logged out. Your code can be well formed and structures in better way. If my suggestion do not help you let me know to see what I can do.

Comment: The problem is, I am not a php developer or expert. My php file is linked to the following : http://amjad-test.site40.net/arabictest.php how can I pass the username to the query

Comment: #maytham I tried my best to make it work. I don't know where my problem is

Comment: This seems like you just need to do some basic debugging: break down the problem, work through step by step. The answer to "how do I get data from the URL?" is trivial - write `?username=foo` on the query string, and access `$_GET['username']`. Test that, with a simple `var_dump($_GET['username'])`. Once you have that, work out how to put that variable into the query; `var_dump` the result, make sure you have all errors visible. And so on. This is all much easier for you to do on your own than waiting hours for us to prompt you each time. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment above is wrong, and your question is literally "how do I pass data from a URL to a PHP script", the answer is that you use [the `$_GET` superglobal variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to access query strings in the standard format `.../path/to/script.php?var1=value1&var2=value2...`

So the URL `http://amjad-test.site40.net/arabictest.php?username=imsop` will execute 'arabictest.php' and populate the variable `$_GET['username']` with the value `'imsop'`. You then use that variable wherever you like in your code.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer help me in fixing the code. I used the rule which says " Divide and Conquer ". I divided the Code into parts. Tested each. Assembled them. It works now